# Aut$(V)$ open subset of End$(V)$

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces

I have read in a book that Aut$(V)$ (set of all invertible linear maps) is an open subset of the End$(V)$ (set of all linear maps), where $V$ is a vector space. Can someone explain under what topology(ies) it is the case?

Comment: What book was that? What kinds of vector spaces does it speak of?

Answer (score 1):

Let $V$ be a *finite-dimensional* vector space (the finite-dimensionality here is of utmost importance). By fixing a basis, you obtain a linear isomorphism $V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$. Now we can take the Euclidean topology and transport is along this isomorphism to obtain a topology on $V$, which makes this isomorphism into a homeomorphism. This topology on $V$ does not depend on the choice of linear isomorphism $V\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, because any other such isomorphism is obtained by composing the first one with a linear automorphism $\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ and these are all homeomorphisms (check this). Thus we obtain a well-defined topology on $V$. One nice property of this topology is that it makes the addition $V\times V\rightarrow V$ and the scalar multiplication $\mathbb{R}\times V\rightarrow V$ (equip the product spaces with the product topologies) into continuous maps (check this as well). This seems like a desirable property and, in fact, it is possible to show that this is the *unique* Hausdorff topology on $V$ with this property, though that takes some more work. All in all, we obtain a canonical topology on $V$. It should be remarked that this is completely false in case $V$ is infinite-dimensional.

Anyway, if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, so is $\mathrm{End}(V)$. In fact, we can choose a basis to identify $V$ with $\mathbb{R}^n$ as above and that naturally yields an identification of $\mathrm{End}(V)$ with the space $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ of $n\times n$-matrices (both as vector spaces and as topological spaces, by the above construction). Now $\mathrm{Aut}(V)$ corresponds to the space $\mathrm{GL}(n)$ of invertible $n\times n$-matrices (as topological space, it carries the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$). From linear algebra, we know a matrix is invertible iff its determinant is non-zero. The determinant can be thought of as function $\det\colon\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and so $\mathrm{GL}(n)=\det^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$. Since $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is open, $\mathrm{GL}(n)$ will be open as long as $\det$ is continuous. But that is clear from the Leibniz formula, which shows that $\det$ is in fact a polynomial.

Comment: additional info for OP: from the determinant reasoning in the last paragraph, it also follows $\text{Aut}(V)$ is also dense in $\text{End}(V)$ (the determinant being a non-zero polynomial cannot vanish identically on a non-empty open set).

Answer (score 1):

For an infinite dimensional example, we have that the set of invertible bounded linear operators on a Banach space is open in the norm topology. This can be shown using [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series#The_set_of_invertible_operators_is_open).

Comment: Additionally the completeness of the space is key. Without this assumption the Neumann series argument no longer works (the convergence of the series is shown using Cauchy sequences), in fact the statement is no longer true. One can consider the space $$c_{00}=\{ (x_n)_{n\geq 1} \subseteq \mathbb{R} \ : \ \text{ only finitely many } x_n \neq 0\}$$ with the sup-norm and the bijective linear operator $$T: c_{00} \rightarrow c_{00}, (x_n)_{n\geq 1} \mapsto (n^{-1} x_n)_{n\geq 1}.$$ You can check that any open neighborhood of $T$ contains a non-invertible operator.